# Hibernate not connecting to oracle database

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, rest

I'm trying to get my application to retrieve results from my Oracle Database through Hibernate. When I hit it with the webservice I get a weird SQL statement (I have hibernate.show_sql set to true). I'm not getting any errors, but I'm not getting any results back either. (I'm very new to hibernate and grateful for any feedback whatsoever.  Thanks)

From Console:

```
INFO: Server startup in 5743 ms
Hibernate: select standards0_.STANDARD_CODE as STANDARD1_0_, standards0_.STANDARD_NAME as STANDARD2_0_, standards0_.STANDARD_TYPE as STANDARD3_0_ from STANDARDS standards0_
0
```

Here's what my table looks like:

```
STANDARDS Columns:
Column Name             Type            Size    Primary Key    Foreign Key    Nullable    Scale
STANDARD_CODE       VARCHAR2        25          true                                            N                
STANDARD_NAME       VARCHAR2        100                                                          N                
STANDARD_TYPE       VARCHAR2        25                                                            N
```

jdbc.properties:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
jdbc.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@myurl:1521:mySID
jdbc.username=MYUSERNAME
jdbc.password=MYPASSWORD
```

persistence-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       ">
    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
        <property name="location" value="classpath:/jdbc.properties"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
        destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}" />
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />     
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}" />
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml" />

        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect</prop>                
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <prop key=" hibernate.use_sql_comments">true</prop>     
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

    <aop:config>
        <aop:pointcut id="webMethods" expression="execution(* com.yourcompany.web.*.*(..))" />
        <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="webMethods" />
    </aop:config>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
        <tx:attributes>
            <tx:method name="*" propagation="REQUIRED" />
        </tx:attributes>
    </tx:advice>
</beans>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <mapping class="com.yourcompany.model.Standards"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

servlet-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
       ">
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.yourcompany" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

MainController.java:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @RequestMapping(value="/admin", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public String admin(){
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List resultsList = session.createQuery("from Standards").list();
        //List resultsList = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM STANDARDS").list();
        System.out.println(resultsList.size());
        for( Standards standards : (List<Standards>) resultsList){
            System.out.println("Event (" + standards.getSTANDARD_CODE() );
        }
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

        return "Return From Admin";
    }       
}
```

Comment: If you got a SQL statement, it means that the app is connected to your database. If you got no result, then it means the table is empty. Where are you looking for the results?

Comment: Well that's good. I know there is data in the table, I'm wondering if I'm hitting the right one. I'm trying to get the results to print to the console for now. Eventually I'd like the push json through a webservice.

Comment: JB, you were right.  Somebody(or i did by accident) deleted the Table data and I was unaware of the changes.  I tried hitting another table and I'm getting some results! Thanks!